# Java: parallel calls of API getList using ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice

I've tried to speed up my code calling two API in parallel.

The first one was

```
List<String> A = aService.getListA();
List<Integer> B = bService.getListB();
```

Now I've changed it into parallel calls like this:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<List<String>> getAs = es.submit(() -> aService.getListA());
        Future<List<Integer>> getBs = es.submit(() -> bService.getListB());
        es.shutdown();
```

It seems to work alright, but I'm not sure if this code is perfect and what would happen in case , for example, if getListB() never answers.

Edit: int change to Integer

Comment: You should probably use the `Future.get()` method on both futures to block until both calls are finished

Comment: `List<int>` is not valid. It must be `List<Integer>`

Comment: do your methods ``getListA()`` and ``getListB()`` do some processing? Otherwise, if you're just getting the references for those lists that parallel call might just be too much.

Comment: `and what would happen in case , for example, if getListB() never answers.` Well, what would happen in the non-parallel case?

Comment: @joao yes they do some processing

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to work alright, but I'm not sure if this code is perfect and what would happen in case , for example, if getListB() never answers.

Answering part two: in that case, your future object just sits there, and any time you call `isDone()`, it would return *false* to you.

In other words: if you want to use some sort of timeout, then you *could* do that on the level that receives that future. On the other hand, it *could* also go **into** that service class. Meaning: the service itself knows about a timeout, and has some way of communicating that to the user.

The actual decision which option works "best" in your case mainly depends on the rest of your design, and the requirements that design should work for. Thus: we can't assess what is best *for you*.